# Poner la fecha actual por Default al calendario

Tags: android

Yo he realizado un metodo que me permite elegir la fecha de un calendario que se muetra y pegar la seleccion en un EditText, pero lo que quiero es que por defecto la fecha del dia actual se aparezca en el EditText, sin tener que estar seleccionando el año, mes y dia del calendario. gracias.

Aqui dejo el codigo que implemente selecionando año, mes y dia.

```
 public void metodo_fecha(View v){
    final Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance();
    dia=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mes=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    ano=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            etfecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
        }
    },dia,mes,ano);
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tu error se debe a que para inicializar correctamente el [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int)) debes usar año, mes y día, NO día, mes, año.**

[DatePickerDialog (Context context, 
                int themeResId, 
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, 
                int year, 
                int monthOfYear, 
                int dayOfMonth)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int))

debe ser:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        etfecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
    }
}, ano, mes, dia /*dia,mes,ano*/);
```

---

tienes que inicializarlo correctamente con los datos de año, mes y día que obtienes a partir del calendario.

```
public void metodo_fecha(View v){
    final Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance();
    dia=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mes=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    ano=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            etfecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
        }
    },ano,mes,dia);
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: public void metodo_horaSalida(View v){
        final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        hora=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minutos=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog =new TimePickerDialog(this, 3,new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                ethorasalida.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
            }
        },hora,minutos,false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }Porque me sale la hora 5:08 como 5:8???   //GRACIASSSSS!

Comment: @PedroNarrea agrega otra pregunta para este caso agregando los detalles, me gustaría ver como te muestra 5:8 :-| , si pudieras agregar una imagen a tu nueva pregunta.

Comment: Oh ya esta bien, gracias

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225041/como-ponerle-formato-a-el-resultado-de-una-fecha , Aqui esta amigo, gracias