# Como ponerle formato a el resultado de una fecha?

Tags: android

he desarrollado un codigo donde pongo en un EditText la hora luego de seleccionarla, con este codigo siguiente el problema que tengo es cuando selecciono una hora como 05:08 me sale en el EditText 5:8 (porque esta en AM) pero si estuviera en PM la misma hora me bota : 17:8.
y ademas cumple todo bien cuando la hora elegida es 17:54 por ejemplo.
gracias!

```
 public void metodo_horaSalida(View v){
    final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    hora=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog =new TimePickerDialog(this, 3,new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            ethorasalida.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
        }
    },hora,minutos,false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Aca se muestra bien [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al elegir esta hora en PM [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bota asi: Este es en PM
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bota asi : Este es en AM
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pedro pero como envías esos valores , tomas el valor entero de onTimeSet() ?

Comment: Hola, no entiendo muy bien esto de las fecha y horas, lo cogi de un tutorial y ahi lo puse y me sale eso :/

Comment: Cual es el tutorial para agregar una respuesta adecuada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtén los valores y agregalos a tu `TextView` o `editText` de esta forma asignando un formato el cual aseguraría mostrar siempre dos dígitos:

```
ethorasalida.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
```

de esta forma, en lugar de mostrar :

```
17:8
```

se mostraría

```
17:08
```

Comment: Si me soluciono el problema, muchas gracias Jorge :)

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @PedroNarrea saudos!