# ¿Obtener datos de numberpicker en edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, numberpicker

Esta es la imagen de mi numberpicker,que al seleccionar solo obtengo 
el dato de un solo numberpicker ejemplo: Feb, quiero obtener los tres datos 
juntos en el edittext cada vez que se seleccione en cualquiera de los numberpicker como por ejemplo: 12 / Jun / 2019 o 12 / 06 /2019 , este el 
código java: no se que estoy haciendo mal por favor ayúdenme

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration2);

    //[Text_Date]
    date = findViewById(R.id.Date);
    //[Numbers_Pickers_Of_Date]
    np_dayOfMonth = findViewById(R.id.nPicker_dayOfMonth);
    np_Month = findViewById(R.id.nPicker_Month);
    np_Year = findViewById(R.id.nPicker_Year);

    //[String and minimum, maximun value for the dayOfMonth]
    final String[] values_dayOfMonth = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
    "21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
    np_dayOfMonth.setDisplayedValues(values_dayOfMonth);
    np_dayOfMonth.setMinValue(01);
    np_dayOfMonth.setMaxValue(31);

    np_dayOfMonth.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            date.setText(values_dayOfMonth[newVal - 1]);
        }
    });

    //Spinner_for_np_dayOfMonth
    np_dayOfMonth.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);


    //[String and minimum, maximun value for the Month]
    final String[] values_Month = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    np_Month.setDisplayedValues(values_Month);
    np_Month.setMinValue(01);
    np_Month.setMaxValue(12);

    np_Month.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            date.setText(values_Month[newVal - 1]);
        }
    });

    //Spinner_for_Month
    np_Month.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

    //[Minimum and maximun for Year]
    np_Year.setMinValue(1919);
    np_Year.setMaxValue(2050);


    //Spinner_for_Year
    np_Year.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porque usas 3 picker y no un DatePicker? por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225018/poner-la-fecha-actual-por-default-al-calendario

Comment: Para crear un selector de fecha personalizado

Comment: ok, agregué una respuesta, usa: date.setText(values_dayOfMonth[np_dayOfMonth.getValue() - 1] + "/" + values_Month[np_Month.getValue()- 1] + "/" + np_Year.getValue());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas usando 3 pickers y a 2 de ellos les estas seteando un `OnValueChangedListener` que, como el nombre lo dice, escucha si se cambia el valor. Entonces cuando cambies el Mes obtendras el valor del mes que cambio y cuando cambies el dia tambien obtendras el dia (al picker del año no se lo pusiste... misterios de la vida).

Primero te sugiero que uses un DatePicker que te solucionaria todos los problemas.

Pero si aun asi estas convencido de usar 3 pickers por cuestiones de diseño, entonces deberas guardar 3 variables, una para cada picker.
Y ademas agregar un metodo que actualice tu TextView donde muestras la fecha. El codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
String day = "1";
String month = "Jan";
String year = "1919";

private void updateDateText(){
   date.setText(day + "/" +  mounth + "/" + year);
}
```

Finalmente para que todo funcione solo debes guardar el dato seleccionado por el picker en la variable que corresponda y luego ejecutar el metodo updateDateText() que te puse ahi arriba.
Te dejo un ejemplo con el picker de los meses:

```
np_Month.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        mounth = values_Month[newVal - 1];//Guardo el valor selccionado en la variable destinada al mes
        updateDateText();
    }
});
```

PD: agregale el OnValueChangedListener al picker del año o nunca te va a andar.

Comment: Si solo selecciono en uno de los numberPicker me da como resultado 
en el edittext esto: 12 / null / null , si seleccionó en las tres obtengo esto : 12 / jun / 1999, debería ser si selecciono en un number picker, obtengo los tres valores tal y cual hace un datepicker, seleccionas en un picker y te da el valor completo y no sale null si no has seleccionado

Comment: Si es posible hacer algo como la que describo desde ya agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Bueno para eso solo agregale valores por defecto a las variables al momento de declararlas, day = "1"; month = "Jan"; year = "1919". Edito la respuesta con esto para que se vea mas claro

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que únicamente estas definiendo un valor cuando se llama el método

```
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            date.setText(....);
        }
    });
```

Debes enviar los 3 valores (día, mes, año) , para esto puedes usar los mismos métodos que tienes para evaluar los valores y usar el método [getValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker) para obtener los valores de cada [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker)

de acuerdo a esto puedes obtener la fecha de esta forma:

```
String fecha = values_dayOfMonth[np_dayOfMonth.getValue() - 1] + "/" + values_Month[np_Month.getValue()- 1] + "/" + np_Year.getValue();
```

o puedes asignarla de esta forma dentro de tus métodos `onValueChange()`:

```
date.setText(values_dayOfMonth[np_dayOfMonth.getValue() - 1] + "/" + values_Month[np_Month.getValue()- 1] + "/" + np_Year.getValue());
```

Comment: En que parte puedo añadir el string 'fecha' :
String fecha = values_dayOfMonth[np_dayOfMonth.getValue() - 1] + "/" + values_Month[np_Month.getValue()- 1] + "/" + np_Year.getValue();

Comment: @freddydiaz en realidad es un ejemplo, te sugiero agregar: date.setText(values_dayOfMonth[np_dayOfMonth.getValue() - 1] + "/" + values_Month[np_Month.getValue()- 1] + "/" + np_Year.getValue()); dentro de onValueChange()

Comment: Ya hice el date.set...dentro del onValueChange pero al agregar + values_Month [np_Month.getValue()- 1] me marca error values_Month no se porque sucede eso

Comment: @freddydiaz que error?

Comment: No puedo agregar el values_Month dentro del date set

Comment: @freddydiaz un poco raro lo que dices, ademàs originalmente si lo realizaste.

Comment: Si lo hice pero al escribir values_Month... el texto se marca de rojo que representa un error

Comment: Si es posible quiero que mi numberpicker me de valores tal y cual haría un datepicker de android

Comment: un poco raro que no puedas acceder al chat, puedes subir tu proyecto en github al menos, estoy seguro que solo es un pequeño detalle de definicion de variables.